# SQL Reporting Services 2005 local time zone

Tags: reporting-services, timezone

We store our date/time information in UTC format on our SQL Server.

When using SQL Reporting Services, we'd like to display this data in the time zone of the client workstation, but it appears that using an expression like;

```
System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Fields!DateStarted.Value)
```

... converts into the time zone of the server, not of the client workstation?

Is there any way of performing this conversion locally, or passing the local time zone to the server for conversion?

Thanks in advance
Matt

Answer (score 1):

If your reports are standalone I can't see other option than add timezone report parameter.

But if you using reports inside web application, you can [Determine Timezone from Request Variables with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338482/can-you-determine-timezone-from-request-variables) and send time zone value back in hidden fields, urlparameter or postback.

You can also add timezone to user registration info (or figure it out from Country and City fields).

Also you may try [Target Your Visitors Using GeoIP and .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/geoip.aspx).

Comment: Yes, agree. SSRS has no support for timezones but these workaround apply.

Comment: The "Determine Your Visitor's Time Zone ..." link appears broken.  I couldn't find it on the site.