# How do Social Networking applications convert server time according to viewer's timezone

Tags: java, javascript, datetime, timezone

How to convert the UTC time according to viewer's timezone?

I *heard* that it's not possible to get the timezone of the viewer, but then how do social networking services like FB, twitter do this ?

Edit: I have registered users on my application.

Comment: [Already there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338482/can-you-determine-timezone-from-request-variables)

Comment: Social networking sites usually ask their customers about their location for their profiles; so later calculating their local time is trivial.

Comment: @SJuan76: but users do travel internationally and they dont need to tell their timezone each time they login from some non-native timezone

Comment: Use the machine local timezone. Anyway do not overwork, it is a website not a clock so if the time is not set to someone's standar is not that important. It is more important that items are kept in order than the actual time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is possible to get the user timezone, but this is done with javascript (get the [detect_timezone.js](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home)). You most likely do that when users are registered.
- Another, worse way is to approximate the timezone based on the IP
- and finally (with combination of any of the above), you can give the user a choice to select his timezone in his settings

Comment: Or use the system time of the client machine (via JS) and just hope that it is correctly set (almost all of time it is).

Comment: that js library checks that as well