# UTC converted to local time

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, gmt

Someone can explain to me how works the conversion of dates from azure database hosted in **GMT 00:00** to client local GMT?

exists some way to convert the date automatically with C#?

have some related with CultureInfo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-sharp-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time

Comment: the example of the link works in web plataform? How the C# will know the GMT of the user for convert the DateTime for the right timezone?

Comment: normally you do that through client side javascript, no?
this post details a bit more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338482/can-you-determine-timezone-from-request-variables

Comment: when the user login into the web site, the timeZoneOffSet is saved into the database user register(in this case GMT -03:00), so i can calculate the local time of the user, but when the date is passed through a json (like this Date(1381795162417) ), the date is adjusted twice resulting in a wrong GMT -06:00, the javascript auto deserialize adjusting to the local time?