# User Timezone in Play 2.5

Tags: playframework

How do I find the Timezone offset of the users Browser in the Play Framework?

I believe I can do so with a little bit of Javascript like this:

```
var tzOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

But getting the Javascript var from the Scala Template to the Controller's seems a bit of overkill.  Plus it won't work for the index page.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You probably meant `var` instead of `val`.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, not all offsets are full-hour ones. There are time offsets with 30 minute increments, even with 45 minutes after the full hour. Don't divide by 60.

Other than that, if you get a time from the Controller, you will get the one from the server, not the user. So, you are pretty much left with what you already have.

See also: [Can You Determine Timezone from Request Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338482/can-you-determine-timezone-from-request-variables?lq=1)